# Better to sand down floor or trim door?

Tags: doors, carpentry

I've been working on installing a sliding "barn" door. Unfortunately, I hung the door too low by about 1/4 inch because the directions that came with the hardware to do so are incorrect. As a point of pride I contacted the company to try understand how I had screwed this up; they confirmed via email with new directions that the hardware measurements in directions were incorrect. Never-the-less this doesn't help me as I have already install the railing and don't want to drill new holes (the railing goes into bare wood so the old holes would not be easy to cover up and would be unsightly). Therefore, I think I'm left with two options. 1) trim the door down or 2) sand the region of the floor where the door makes contact. 1) seems like the obvious answer, but will break the symmetry of the door and bothers my aesthetics. 2) would require sanding a 2 inch x 1.5 inch section of the wood floor (near the wall) down 1/8 - 1/4 inch and then refinishing that section of the floor. The house is old so the floor slopes away from that point and the spacing isn't an issue anywhere else. My question is if this is feasible and/or a reasonable approach and if there are any potential issues with doing this?
[image][image][image]

Comment: Assuming the door 'slides' on wheels on a rail, maybe the company could send you some slightly larger wheels or a new wider rail.   After all, they were at fault.

Comment: please post a link to the door slide hardware so that we can see what it looks like

Comment: ah yeah... floor sanding is easier in the middle of the room so the edges often get too little attention. but unless you want to resurface the both rooms, trimming the door, or repositioning the bardware  is your best move.

Comment: Your floor has a stain or aged poly on it; new poly will never match, so if you thought the door would be noticeable, think about how bad a huge spot of off-color flooring right in the front door will come off.

Comment: What symmetry are you concerned about? I'd also like to see the hardware. Chances are there's a no-cut solution to be had there.

Comment: @isherwood , I believe there is too. All the hardware I seen that mounts to the wall or header has a larger base, maybe about 1 1/4" to 1 1/2". This should allow the whole track to be raised close to 3/8"- 1/2" so the lag bolts will find new wood to tap into, but for insurance, fill the old holes anyway to keep the drill running the new pilot holes in its' place. The larger bases will cover the old mounting holes.... barely.... but enough...

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Here's a [link] https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07HHSP7F7/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 to the hardware:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing that you have a solid wood door, it would be no issue to cut the bottom off the 1/4"+ to get it to clear the floor. If you have an electric door planer would be the simplest way to trim the bottom, using extreme care on starting and stopping the cuts. The typical way of cutting the bottom is with a circular saw, protecting the door from scratches from the shoe of the saw, and scoring the face of the door to minimize splintering from cutting.

Comment: I agree. To clarify, score the surface of the door just _above_ where you'll cut. After your cut, sand the edges a bit to bevel them, which will prevent future damage and eliminate the score mark. If you cut right on the score you'll still have tearout.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I left it kinda open, so if the OP had more questions as to how to proceed with either type of cut, those details would get filled in. but I should have included it from the start.... So much for answering really really late at night....

Comment: "If you have an electric door planer" I'd suspect that most people who have one of these would _not_ be asking the question the OP posted. Not to say you're wrong, but, it's pretty reasonable to assume the OP does _not_ have one....

Comment: That's why the "if", I figured that would be the case, but it is an alternative if one was handy and the easiest way to make the cut without chipping the face of the door if used properly.